# Huge File Size with Embedded Font (Used Characters Only) in PowerPoint

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, size, embedded-fonts

I have a PowerPoint file. I used 2 custom fonts on my document, so I decided to embed the fonts in the file using the "Embed Fonts" option available in PowerPoint.

[Settings Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBGPL.png)

Without font embedding, the file size was **483kB**. After enabling the option (embedding "only the characters used"), the file size blew up to **14MB**.

Exported to a PDF, the file size was only 600kB.

I only have about 50 letters in my document, it seems strange that the file size should grow this much. Is there a way to effectively reduce the file size so that it can be emailed? The fonts do not necessarily have to be embedded; it just needs to be in the PowerPoint format (not in PDF) and correctly displayed when presented from another device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clearly stated in title and text that you set the "Save As" Used Characters Only and that will have reduced the size, but have not shown any example of content.

So here is a small single page, we can see it is only 37 KB when save as no fonts (much less than that for the used characters)

[image]

Clearly if all the fonts used and more are included it will blossom to 22 MB, and as you attempted save Used characters Only will be 1/10 the size at under 2 MB.

The issue is it depends on the variability of the included fonts as to how much space each subset requires some fonts can be huge if compositing highly detailed glyphs.

To find out which is the worst offender you can save the pptx as a zip file and extract as if a simple folder.

[image]

Based on that you may decide to restyle those characters to match a different font that uses less storage however *"It is, what it is"* and you are unlikely to reduce the file size by much, that way.

Answer (score 0):

When embedding fonts, PowerPoint may embed more than you demanded.

Below is quoted an excellent post by Nicholas_W :
[Managing file size when embedding custom fonts in PowerPoint](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/managing-file-size-when-embedding-custom-fonts-in/c35dc8ec-2c38-49d0-979e-eb35995a3834).

> When you embed a custom font in a PowerPoint template, the file size
> increases by approximately the size of the fonts used in the document.
> To facilitate editing, PowerPoint also embeds Regular, Bold, Italic,
> Bold Italic weights of the fonts used in the document. If you use
> bullets, then fonts such as Calibri may be included.
>
> To reduce the file size, only embed the font you want. Follow these
> steps to make sure standard fonts like Calibri are not embedded in
> your document.
>
> 1. Select **View** from the ribbon, and then select **Slide Master**.
> 2. In Slide Master ribbon tab, select **fonts**, then select **Customize fonts**.
> 3. Select the Heading font and Body font for the font you want (if you need complex script support then those can be specified as well).
> 4. Select **Save**.
> 5. Select **Close Master View**.
> 6. Select **File**, then **Options**, then select **Save**.
> 7. In the right side of PowerPoint Options dialog, Select the option **Embed fonts in the file** and next choose **Embed all characters**.
> 8. Select **Ok**.
>
> PowerPoint will embed fonts on the next save.
>
> If you’ve already embedded multiple fonts, you can remove them by
> following these steps:
>
> 1. Select **File**, then **Options**, and then **Save**.
> 2. In the right side of PowerPoint Options dialog, unselect the option Em**bed fonts in the file** and next choose **Embed all characters**
> 3. Select **Ok**
>
> PowerPoint will remove all embedded fonts on the next save.
>
> Note: Microsoft Office checks the embedding rights of each font before
> embedding. Fonts which do not have embedding privileges are not
> embedded. To understand embedding privileges, check out the
> [OpenTypespec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/os2#fstype).

Selecting "Embed all characters" will embed only the characters
used in the text, as distinct from embedding the font's entire
character set, including special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Notice this sentence in the quote above:

*To facilitate editing, PowerPoint also embeds Regular, Bold, Italic, Bold Italic weights of the fonts used in the document. If you use bullets, then fonts such as Calibri may be included.*

PPT would be embedding several weights of each font. That would add to the embedded font size.

Also, choose the Replace Fonts dialog to see what fonts PowerPoint thinks are in use; sometimes there are more fonts than you expect. These will also be embedded, if only partially.